# Understanding the CMB power spectrum

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

We are able to expand the CMB temperature anisotropy map in terms of spherical harmonics.

[image]

My current understanding is that each l (on the x-axis of the power spectrum below) corresponds to a unique spherical harmonic of degree l in our expansion. While the corresponding y value is the coefficient of that spherical harmonic in the expansion. Is this correct? If so, since there are multiple choices for a spherical harmonic with degree l, what are the 'special' spherical harmonics that correspond to each l on the x-axis? And why are they chosen?

[image: The CMB Power Spectrum]

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#:~:text=The%20CMB%20has%20a%20thermal,6.626%20%E2%8B%85%2010%E2%88%924%20eV. This would be a good place to start, they mention how they remove the m dependence directly in data reduction and analysis section.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll check it out!